# ltng:require not able to save syntax error?

Tags: lightning, static-resources

I want to load in two static resource js files. My code:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',' $Resource.resource1, $Resource.resource2)}"/>
```

On save attempt, I get the following error:

> expecting a right parenthesis, found '$Resource' at column 10 of expression: join(',' $Resource.resource1, $Resource.resource2):

I tried sticking the two resources into two different ltng:require, which means I can save the page:

```
<ltng:require scripts="{! $Resource.fileStack }"/>
<ltng:require scripts="{! $Resource.filestackConnector }"/>
```

but then I get error:

> Custom Script Eval error in "ltng:require" [SecureDOMEvent: [object Event](key: {"namespace":"c"}}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed comma after `','`. It should be

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', $Resource.resource1, $Resource.resource2)}"/>
```

Check [Expression Functions Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm).

> Joins the substrings adding the separator String (first argument)
>   between each subsequent argument.

It has arguments, first is separator and all arguments should be separated by a comma.